# Statically linking Casablanca/CPPREST SDK

Tags: visual-c++, cpprest-sdk

I am trying to create a Windows-based VC++ DLL (in VS 2015) that statically links to the Casablanca CPPREST SDK.  That is, I would like a single DLL output which contains the CPP REST library along with my code.

I have referred to this thread, however it seems rather dated (and has broken links):

https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2014/04/01/how-to-statically-link-the-c-rest-sdk-casablanca/

I have tried to download the Casablanca repo from GitHub and compile the "cpprestsdk140.static" project which produces a lib file.  The problem is I get a number of unresolved externals when linking it with my project.

Numerous people have commented on the unresolved link errors in the above-mentioned URL.  There are also numerous threads on Github with people saying they cannot link simple projects with the static library.

Does anyone have a clear set of steps that can help resolve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, I pooled together a number of suggestions from the various threads and have the following set of steps in order to successfully link to the CPP REST static library:

1. Download Casablanca SDK from https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk.  (via GIT Clone or Zip).
2. Open the VS solution and right-click on the properties of the *cpprestsdk140.static*.
3. In the *C++* -> *Preprocessor definitions*, add **CPPREST_EXCLUDE_COMPRESSION**.  The full list looks like: *_NO_ASYNCRTIMP;_ASYNCRT_EXPORT;_PPLX_EXPORT;WIN32;_MBCS;_USRDLL;CPPREST_EXCLUDE_COMPRESSION;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)*
4. In *Librarian* -> *General* -> *Additional dependencies*, add **crypt32.lib;winhttp.lib;** (See https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/344)
5. Press OK, then build the *cpprestsdk140.static* project.  You will end up with a **libcpprest140d_2_9.lib** (for Debug build) in the *Binaries* directory.

Now, in your own project:

1. If you have previously used the Nuget version of CPPREST, firstly ensure you remove any references in the Nuget package manager.
2. Right-click your project properties and go to *C++* -> *Additional Include Directories* and enter the path for the CPPREST SDK include files.  They currently reside in *cpprestsdk\Release\include*.
3. Now go to *C++* -> *Preprocessor definitions*, add **_NO_ASYNCRTIMP** (See https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/124).
4. Go to *Linker* -> *Input* and add **libcpprest140d_2_9.lib** (along with pathname, if applicable).  For the release version, it appears you also need to add **crypt32.lib;winhttp.lib**.
5. Build your project and hopefully all is well  ;)

I hope this helps someone (I'm sure it will)!

Comment: As a side note, if you link to `bcrypt.lib;crypt32.lib;winhttp.lib;` for the cpprest static library itself, then you wouldn't need to link to these libraries again in your own project

Comment: This worked like a charm for vc142! I didn't end up needing the step for  CPPREST_EXCLUDE_COMPRESSION. The static libs need to be available in NuGet to save a lot of time. I did notice WIN32 was set on the 64-bit build.

Comment: I put my compiled v142 x64 binaries here - https://github.com/tgraupmann/Cpp_BoostJsonZipPostJwt/releases

Comment: There's one more detail needed. Somehow a dependency on the DLL version of the library is being added instead of the static libraries for `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`. It's working, but I'd like to statically link both.

Comment: Looks like I just need to build static libs for those two libraries. Ther openssl-vc142 and static lib Nuget packages still had a dependency on the DLLs.

Comment: This video is the most comprehensive instructions for building shared and static versions of OpenSSL - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMHEoBkxYaQ - This has all the steps and way better than the OpenSSL instructions and Windows notes.

Answer (score 7):

One more addition to the Simple Guy's answer:
If you use `http_listener` class in your project it is likely you will need `Httpapi.lib` to fix linker errors.

And also I want to propose an easier way to compile a static cpprestdk library. 
I've successfully used it to build my project in VS2017.

1. install vcpkg from https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg
2. Compile cpprestsdk using following commands:

   Step 1. `vcpkg install cpprestsdk:x86-windows-static`

   Step 2. `vcpkg install cpprestsdk:x64-windows-static`
3. Follow the second part of Simple Guy's answer starting from your project settings. Additionally, use my advice from above and BobC to fix linker errors.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you. Since compression is not excluded during compilation of cpprestsdk using vcpkg, zlib.lib also needs to be added.

Comment: I used your approached and linked the resulting library but I get link time errors, should I only link to the resulting `cpprest_2_10.lib` library? Do I need to add additional libs?

Comment: added httpapi.lib in my project for using cpprestsdk 2.10.x, it resolve my last linker error :)

Comment: If anyone else is working on a project that requires runtime library of multi-threaded debug for Debug configuration and multi-threaded for Release and ran into "mismatched runtime library" errors, you can add `<VcpkgTriplet Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">x64-windows-static</VcpkgTriplet>` to .vcproj as shown in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-updates-static-linking-is-now-available/ to fix the issues. Release will use the static build.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Simple Guy said, you will probably need to add bcrypt.lib to the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies since the OAuth1.obj file in CPPRest depends on some of those functions.