# How to statically link cpprest without dll files in VS project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I finally linked Casablanca/CPPRESTSDK with VS17, thanks for this post [Statically linking Casablanca/CPPREST SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905708/statically-linking-casablanca-cpprest-sdk/44910349) and some anothers. But now I see, that when I start project, for some reason VS automatically generates 3 DLL files `zlib1.dll` `SSLEAY32.dll` `LIBEAY32.dll` in folder with .exe, but I actually linked staticly for not to have them at all. I also have these files in lib format in `vcpkg-master\installed\x86-windows-static\lib`, can I somehow use them instead of dlls?

Comment: It seems that you want to statically link all of the cpprestsdk's dependencies, and dependencies of those dependencies recursively. Also note that files with `.lib` extension are not necessary static libraries, they can be import libraries for linking dlls.

Comment: I just want to have 1 .exe file in my project, without any dll's.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have a Visual Studio solution with projects using MFC in a shared DLL and using the multi-threaded DLL runtime library. I wanted to link statically to cpprestsdk without three extra DLLs to distribute. Linking to the static version of cpprestsdk wasn't working: I couldn't link because of conflicting runtime libraries (`/MT` - multithreaded and `/MD` - multi-threaded DLL). I couldn't find a pre-compiled version which used the `/MD` switch (multi-threaded DLL), but exported as a library. So I had to compile it myself.

My solution:

- download `vcpkg` (https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg). This is a package C and C++ library package manager. You will need to 'bootstrap' it. See the Quick Start.
- install necessary dependencies for cpprestsdk: `vcpkg install --triplet x86-windows zlib openssl boost-system boost-date-time boost-regex boost-interprocess websocketpp brotli
- download cpprestsdk from github (https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk)
- generate a Visual Studio solution file (https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-build-for-Windows). I wanted to generate an x86 version, so I had to use the following command `cmake ../Release -A win32 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_F  ILE=d:\jw\git\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`.
- open `cpprestsdk.sln` solution and do the following for Release and Debug configurations in the `cpprest` project:

  - change the configuration type to Static library
  - change the target file extension to `.lib`.
  - build debug and release versions.

I could then use the generated libraries in my solution.

- add the cpprestsdk include directory to my project
- add the cpprestsdk libraries to the linker Input
- add the zlib and openssl libraries from the cpprestsdk `packages` directory.
- add the libraries `bcrypt.lib`, `winhttp.lib` and `crypt32.lib` to the linker Input too ([Statically linking Casablanca/CPPREST SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905708/statically-linking-casablanca-cpprest-sdk))
- you also need to add the preprocessor flag `_NO_ASYNCRTIMP` to the project where you use cpprestsdk.

I hope this helps someone save some of the hours I lost getting it to work!